# Publish a Samsung gear s2 app

Tags: samsung-gear, samsung-gear-s2

I want to publish a tizen app (targeted only for gear s2) to Samsung store. Is it possible to target only for S2 and not for gear S? If it is possible, is there any source/info on how to publish an tizen gear s2 app on samsung store?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in Tizen store after uploading the binary you can select "Supported Devices".

Store URL is http://seller.tizenstore.com/login/signIn.as

[image]